# How can I find entries that match a certain array of values with the mongo ruby driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I know I can find entries in mongodb that match a certain array of values natively via this command:

```
db.vendors.find({"somearray.property": { $in: ["value1","value2"]}})
```

But how can I do this with the ruby driver 'mongo' gem?

```
col.find("somearray.property" => ["value1","value2"])
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
col.find("somearray.property" => { '$in' => ["value1","value2"] })
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what you mean by the "ruby driver" but if you are using [mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html) (which I recommend when dealing with mongodb) you can do

```
col.where(:'somearray.property'.in => ["val1", "val2"])
```

More informations [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#queries)

Comment: Sorry for vagueness, I mean the 'mongo' ruby gem. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver